# Regex is not matching properly

Tags: java, regex, java-8

The below code always print "no". Any ideas ?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Rextester
{  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String field= "superCategory(code)[composite={catalog: $catalog}]";

        Pattern FULL_PATTERN = Pattern
            .compile("\\[composite\\s*=\\s*\\{([^)]+)\\}\\]");

        final Matcher matcher = FULL_PATTERN.matcher(field);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
          System.out.println("yes");
        } else {
          System.out.println("no");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `.find()` instead of `.matches()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `find` the pattern, not `matches`:

```
if (matcher.find()) {
```